# Whence the 27 digits of extra precision in `decimal.Decimal(1.0/3.0)`?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

This post is about the number of **[significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)** in the expression `decimal.Decimal(1.0/3.0)`.

The documentation for `decimal.Decimal` says that ["[t]he significance of a new Decimal is determined solely by the number of digits input"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial).

From this it follows, I think, that the number of significant digits in `decimal.Decimal(1.0/3.0)` should be determined by the number of significant digits in the IEEE 754 double resulting from the operation `1.0/3.0`.

Now, it is my understanding that an IEEE 754 64-bit double has a "[15-17 significant decimal digits precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)".

Therefore, taking all of the above together, I expect that `decimal.Decimal(1.0/3.0)` will have at most 17 significant decimal digits.

It appears however, that `decimal.Decimal(1.0/3.0)` is given at least 54 significant decimal digits:

```
import decimal
print decimal.Decimal(1.0/3.0)

# 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
```

Two key questions boil down from all this:

1. what is the basis for the claim that an IEEE 754 double has ["a 15-17 significant decimal digits precision"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)?
2. how to resolve the contradiction among the following items?:

   1. the documentation for `decimal.Decimal` cited above
   2. the 54 (or more) significant digits in `decimal.Decimal(1.0/3.0)`
   3. the maximum of 17 for the significant decimal digits in an IEEE 754 double.

---

**Addendum:** OK, I now have a better understanding of the situation, thanks ajcr's answer, and several additional comments.

Internally, `decimal` represents `1.0/3.0` as the fraction

```
6004799503160661/18014398509481984
```

The denominator of this fraction is 2<sup>54</sup>.  The numerator is (2<sup>54</sup> - 1)/3, *exactly*.

The decimal representation of this fraction is, *exactly*

```
0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
```

---

**Addendum 2:**  One more try.  A floating point number *F* is a stand-in for an uncountable *set* of real numbers.  This set of values includes the rational number *Q*(*F*) that is *exactly* represented by the floating point number *F*.  It also includes uncountably many real values above and below *Q*(*F*).  Now, given a real number *R* within the range of 64-bit IEEE 754 double, let *F*(*R*) be the double that *R* gets mapped to when it is represented as a floating point number <sup>1</sup>.

For example, if *R* = 1/3, then *F*(*R*) is the IEEE 754 double given by the following 64 bits:

```
0 01111111101 0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101 = F(R)
```

...and *Q*(*F*(*R*)) is the fraction *N*/*D*, where *D* = 2<sup>54</sup> = 18014398509481984, and *N* = (2<sup>54</sup> - 1)/3 = 6004799503160661.  In short:

```
6004799503160661/18014398509481984 = Q(F(R))
```

or, alternatively, as an *exact* decimal:

```
0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 = Q(F(R))
```

But the floating point *F*(*R*) stands in not only for *R* = 1/3 and *Q*(*F*(*R*)) = *N*/*D*, but also for all the real numbers
in the range (*A*, *B*) <sup>2</sup>, where *A* = (2​*N* - 1)/2​*D*, and *B* = (2​*N* + 1)/2​*D*.  Below I show the *exact* decimal representations of *A* < *Q*(*F*(*R*)) < *B*, together with a 54-digit *inexact* representation of *R* = 1/3:

```
0.3333333333333332593184650249895639717578887939453125   = A
0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 = Q(F(R))
0.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 ~ R
0.33333333333333337034076748750521801412105560302734375  = B
```

Now, here are the decimal representations of the same four numbers *A*, *Q*(*F*(*R*)), *R*, and *B*, but now rounded to 17 significant figures:

```
0.33333333333333326 ~ A
0.33333333333333331 ~ Q(F(R))
0.33333333333333333 ~ R
0.33333333333333337 ~ B
```

This should at least explain why IEEE 754 doubles are said to have "15-17 significant decimal digits precision".  More explicitly, the decimal representations of any two *real* numbers represented by a given IEEE 754 double will agree at between 15 and 17 of their most significant figures.

OK, back to *Q*(*F*(*R*)).  Yes, this is a rational number whose denominator is a power of 2, and therefore we can compute its decimal expansion *exactly*.  The number of significant figures in this expansion is literally infinite.  But this number's role here is strictly as the canonical representative of an uncountable set of real numbers, and all these numbers share at most 17 significant figures.  Therefore, to use any more significant figures in the expansion of *Q*(*F*(*R*)) amounts to a *misrepresentation* of this set of real numbers.  IOW, the least significant 27 figures in the decimal expansion of *Q*(*F*(*R*)) are, in this sense, extraneous, irrelevant, indeed **not significant**, with respect to the role of *Q*(*F*(*R*)) as a stand-in for all the numbers in (*A*, *B*), including *R*.

To put it differently, when acting in its role as representative of the interval (*A*, *B*), *Q*(*F*(*R*)) should be just

```
0.33333333333333331 ~ Q(F(R))
```

The rest of its decimal expansion is not germane to this role, and therefore, it should be kept out of view.

I realize that it may be too difficult to do design `decimal` any better than it is, given all the demands placed on it.  IOW, the misrepresentation described above may be, practically speaking, unavoidable.  At least, however, it should be clear documented, along with all the other more-or-less unavoidable misrepresentations connected with floating point numbers.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Yes, I am maintaining the distinction between the IEEE 754 double *F*(*R*) (a particular sequence of bits in memory), and the rational number *Q*(*F*(*R*)) (a mathematical entity), just to be absolutely clear.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I suppose it also includes one of the endpoints of this range, but this detail is not important here.</sup>

Comment: This has nothing to do with Decimal, or digits of precision, or anything; you pass in floats, you are subject to floating-point issues.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I am perfectly aware of "floating-point issues".  What I am trying to understand is why the default decimal precision of a floating point number not taken to be something closer to the theoretically correct "15-17" digits.

Comment: This is either a duplicate, or a *really interesting* question about a subtle issue. (and it is too late at night here for me to tell)

Comment: " "surprise" is relative. " yes, It's up to you to decide what precision you really need. this implementation just keeps the exact value of the input intact.

Comment: "A floating point number F is a stand-in for an uncountable set of real numbers." <- I think this is your problem. This is not the IEEE 754 philosophy. IEEE 754 regards a floating-point number as a single exact value, and all operations are based on that exact value.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks for this clarification.  I did not get to read it until I had already written another comment to you elsewhere in this thread.  I'm not sure that my misundertanding of the IEEE 754 philosophy entirely invalidates the point I made in that comment, so I won't delete it, but I may have written it somewhat differently if I had first read the point you made here.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: The formulation you highlighted above was my attempt to explain to myself why an IEEE 754 64-bit double is said to have "15-17 significant decimal digits precision".  With it I was able to recover exactly the right number of significant digits (as explained in my Addendum 2).  This gave me some confidence that I was on the right track.  You say, however, that I'm not.  I totally take your word for it, but then I would like to know how else one derives this estimate of "15-17 significant decimal digits precision" for IEEE 754 64-bit doubles.

Comment: You can have many real numbers that agree to more than 17 digits of a floating-point number. For example, take your floating-point value for 1/3 and alter it in its 54th digit, 53rd digit, etc. Also, be aware that inputs that are exact to begin with, like a large negative power of two, can have hundreds of significant digits.

Comment: The 15 and 17 digit thresholds derive from what makes conversions round-trip: decimal inputs 15 digits or less are guaranteed to round-trip through (double-precision) floating-point, and floating-point inputs of 17 digits or more are guaranteed to round-trip through decimal. My blog, Exploring Binary, is one place where you can read more about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When passed a float, Decimal uses the [`from_float`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Lib/decimal.py#l709) constructor. This class method constructs a Decimal from a single Python float *exactly*; it doesn't know that how the float was calculated and that is might be considered by humans to be accurate only to a certain number of digits.

Instead, it determines the appropriate number of digits to take from the float by considering it as a ratio of two integers. This is at line 740:

```
n, d = abs(f).as_integer_ratio()
k = d.bit_length() - 1
result = _dec_from_triple(sign, str(n*5**k), -k)
```

This means for `1.0/3.0` we have the following:

```
>>> f = 1.0 / 3.0
>>> f.as_integer_ratio()
(6004799503160661, 18014398509481984)
>>> (18014398509481984).bit_length()
55
```

To construct the decimal, the sign, coefficient and exponent are calculated and passed to `_dec_from_triple`. In this case the coefficient is the string:

```
'333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125'
```

and the exponents is `-(55-1)`. This gives the decimal exactly 54 digits of accuracy after the decimal point, hence your observation.

Comment: So `k = d.bit_length - 1`, the binary precision, is used as the ***decimal*** precision?  If so, that's got to be a bug.

Comment: Might be worth adding that in the ``1. / 3.`` example, ``Decimal`` shows the exact value in memory and printing will truncate to the significant digits. If you print the result with 60 digits, it will be padded with 0.

Comment: @kjo It's not a bug. You get a decimal place for every "binary place". For example, consider 3/64. That is 0.046875 in decimal, or 0.000011 in binary.

Comment: @RickRegan: Thanks for your comment.  I was about write a comment of my own starting with "on a second thought, it's not the bug I thought it was at first."  I have not yet convinced myself, however, that it is not at least a "design bug" (i.e. a bad design, even if correctly implemented), but in order to do this, I need to understand better what the `decimal` code is doing.  I'm working on this at the moment.

Comment: @kjo I don't understand what you mean by "bad design". It's just math: every time you multiply the binary fraction by ten you shift one binary place and one decimal place to the left (you remove a power of two).

Comment: @RickRegan: when I wrote about "bad design" I was not referring specifically to your comment, but more generally to the design of `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: @kjo: What makes you think it's a bug? Look at the decimal representations of 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc., and notice that you get exactly one extra *decimal* digit each time.

Comment: @kjo: And the design was carefullly chosen, and deliberate. It's not a design bug, either. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks.  I did arrive at the conclusion that it is neither a numerical nor a design bug.  (It may be a documentation bug, but I have not read the documentation closely enough to do it justice.)  I'll write down my reasoning as an addendum to my post.

Comment: @kjo: Yes, the docs could be improved. In a nutshell, *most* of the decimal operations have the notion of an "ideal exponent" - this comes from the specification. The specification doesn't cover conversion from binary float, though. We decided that the "ideal exponent" for conversion from float should be 0: that is, the result of the conversion uses the closest exponent to 0 that permits the exact value of the float to be represented. (IOW, that's zero for integral floats, and the least negative exponent in other cases.) The docs should probably mention this.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: On more thought, there *is* a bug, *somewhere*.  The docs say **"[t]he significance of a new Decimal is determined solely by the number of digits input."**  It is not entirely clear what this means when the input is a double (rather than, say, a string like `'0.333'`), but I think in this case the most reasonable interpretation would be that the significance [of `decimal.Decimal(<DOUBLE>)`] is determined solely by the *significance* of `<DOUBLE>`.  ...

Comment: @MarkDickinson: ...The current behavior of `decimal.Decimal` clearly violates this description.  For example, as described in my post, `decimal.Decimal(1.0/3.0)` behaves as if it had at least 54 significant digits, whereas `1.0/3.0`, being an IEEE 754 double, has at most 17 significant digits.  One could debate whether this amounts to a bug in the documentation, or in the design, or in the implementation, but something is definitely wrong somewhere.

Comment: "1.0/3.0, being an IEEE 754 double, has at most 17 significant digits".  It really doesn't.  The result of 1.0/3.0 is a Python float. That float has an exact value, and that exact value is `0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125`. This is all before we get anywhere near the decimal module.  Then when converted to Decimal, the decimal module simply uses that same exact value.

Answer (score 4):

With 'Decimal(1.0/3.0)' you are converting the result of the float division, which you have demonstrated is incorrect, to Decimal. What you meant to do was:

```
>>>> Decimal("1.0")/Decimal("3.0")
Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333')
```

On the nature of floating-point numbers:

> My understanding is that a 64-bit double "gives a 15-17 significant decimal digits precision".

There is no more information in the input to Decimal() than a single floating-point number. It doesn't know that it is the result of an arithmetic operation; You could have called it like `Decimal(0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125)`, after all.

This is why Decimals should always be constructed from strings or integers: Those don't suffer from this ambiguity.

Comment: @kjo Have you considered the possibility that you're the one who's having difficulty reading (and writing)?  Everyone is, in fact, answering the question you asked.  Try reading the answers again.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of the confusion derives from a misinterpretation of IEEE 754 floating point.

It is not an interval arithmetic system. Each floating point number has a single precisely defined value. The result for each calculation is the result of rounding to nearest starting from the result of applying the corresponding real number operation to the specified values of the inputs.

1.0/3.0 is the closest representable value to the result of the real number division 1.0/3.0. It is not the result of division of the range [9999999.99999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375,10000000.0000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125] by the range [29999999.999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375,30000000.000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625].

Extra rounding steps will tend to increase rounding error, which is generally undesirable unless there is a additional data justifying the rounding.

Comment: Thanks!  As I wrote to Mark Dickinson, I invoked intervals in my Addendum 2 in an effort to explain to myself why IEEE 754 doubles are said to have "15-17 significant decimal digits".  If the intervals-based interpretation is invalid for some reason, then I would like to know how else one arrives at the "15-17 significant decimal digits".

Comment: In fact, the statement that "[e]ach floating point number has a single precisely defined value" implies that the number of significant decimal digits in a floating point number is infinite.  (I interpret "precisely defined value" as meaning "infinite precision".  E.g. 1/2 = 0.5000000000..., where all the digits are the decimal point are significant.)  IOW, that assertion directly contradicts the claim that IEEE 754 doubles have "15-17 significant decimal digits."  I am trying to sort out this apparent contradiction.

Comment: "significant digits" is used with different meanings in different situations. I think you are taking a definition that would be used in writing down a measurement. No physical measurement is exact, so you never need to write an infinite string of trailing zeros. In this context, it is to do with the number of digits needed to distinguish two adjacent representable values, or the number of digits that will be preserved when rounding an in-range real to a representable value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The quote I got on the "15-17 significant decimal digits" comes from the Wikipedia article on IEEE 754 doubles.  Do you agree with that quote, and if so, which of the two senses of "significant figures" you give applies to it?

Comment: @kjo The rest of the paragraph says more precisely what the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) means by it: "If a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double precision representation and then converted back to a string with the same number of significant digits, then the final string should match the original. If an IEEE 754 double precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 17 significant digits and then converted back to double, then the final number must match the original".

Comment: Thank you.  FWIW, that definition is entirely consistent with the one I've been thinking of all along.  I think of that definition as an "operational equivalent" of the one I proposed in terms of representatives and intervals, which explains (at least to me) the basis for the operational definition, in terms of the underlying math.

Comment: @kjo The only problem with your model is that it is not the model on which the standard and its implementations were based, so it makes it harder to understand some of the decisions, such as why the correct conversion to decimal of 1.0/3.0 is 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125. That is obvious under the model where every finite double number has a specific rational number value.